# insert data from session array in laravel 6

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array, laravel-6

**`i want to insert a record of form fields in table and also values from session array`**

i have a form with following fields

```
name,email,address
```

and i have session array `'cartS'` like this

```
"cartS": [
  {
    "pid": "1",
    "qnty": "3"
  },
  {
    "pid": "2",
    "qnty": "2"
  }
],
```

so i have a table in which following fields

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id(auto increment)  uid(user's id)   pid(product id)   qnty(quantity)   name   email   address
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here i have `model` called order model

i have one `controller` in which there is `public function placeorder(Request $request)`

i can get value from  form-fields using `$request`

but what about `pid` and `qnty` which are in session array(associative array)

**if i do foreach loop then it only gives value of one key but i have 2 keys in session array**

```
$sessionCart=Session::get('cartS');

foreach($sessionCart as $key=>$value){
    $pid=$value['pid'];
    $qnty=$value['qnty'];
}
```

if i `return $pid` then it gives only first key's `pid` but not all

following is my **`placeorder function`**

```
public function placeOrder(Request $request){

        $sessionUser=Session::get('userS'); // user's name,email are stored in sessionarray called 'userS'
        $sessionEmail=$sessionUser['email']; // i am accessing email of session user 
  
        $getUid=customerModel::where('email',$sessionEmail)->count();
       // counting userid(uid) from table which should be only one unique in table

        if($getUid==1){
            $uid=customerModel::where('email',$sessionEmail)->value('uid');
            // here i am getting uid of that user
            
            // here i am requesting value of form field

            $name=$request->name;
            $email=$request->email;
            $address=$request->address;
            $order=new orderModel;
            
            $sessionCart=Session::get('cartS');
            if($sessionCart){

            // if $sessioncart is true then following code should run and rest is my garbage code.....

                foreach($sessionCart as $key=>$value){
                    $pid=$value['pid'];
                    $qnty=$value['qnty'];
                }   

                    $order->uid=$uid;
                    $order->pid=$pid;
                    $order->quantity=$qnty;
                    $order->customer_name=$name;
                    $order->customer_email=$email;
                    $order->address=$address;
                    $order->save();
                return redirect('checkout');
            }
            else{
                return back();
            }
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/');
        }
        
    }
```

**i don't know if i am right or wrong by writing above function but i want to insert record like following**

**if it is not good approach then kindly suggest one : )**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id(auto increment)  uid(user's id)   pid(product id)   qnty(quantity)   name   email         address
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   1                1-2               3-2             xyz     test@test.com   xyz
```

here i am trying to insert `value of pid and qnty` are using `implode/explode`

honestly i've never tried `implode/explode`

or

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id(auto increment)  uid(user's id)   pid(product id)   qnty(quantity)   name   email         address
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   1                1               3            xyz     test@test.com   xyz 
1                   1                2               2            xyz     test@test.com   xyz
```

please give your suggestions-answers whatever etc : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are 2 products in your cart, (i think)  you must have 2 records in order table, also you need to add one more column to group orders, for example order_tag which will contain unique string
Second way is to divide orders table in two tables

```
orders(id,user_id,name,email,address, order_status)
order_items(id,order_id,product_id,qnty,price)
```

Then you can easily find(query) orders detail. Saving products will look like that

```
if($sessionCart){

        // if $sessioncart is true then following code should run and rest is my garbage code.....
    $order=new orderModel;
    $order->uid=$uid;
    $order->customer_name=$name;
    $order->customer_email=$email;
    $order->address=$address;
    $order->save();
    foreach($sessionCart as $key=>$value){
       $pid=$value['pid'];
       $qnty=$value['qnty'];
       $orderItem = new OrderItem;
       $orderItem->order_id = $order->id;
       $orderItem->product_id=$pid;
       $orderItem->quantity=$qnty;
       $orderItem->save()

    }   
           
    return redirect('checkout');
}
```